# Are first official science images of JWST are most far distant images ever taken by space telescope?

Tags: nasa, james-webb-telescope

In [JWST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope), it says:

> NASA has scheduled the **first official science images** release event for Tuesday, 12 July 2022 at 10:30 am EDT/usa.

Are first official science images of JWST are most far distant images ever taken by space telescope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Maybe - A Deep Field Is Included

The list of the first targets of JWST to be released on July 12 includes a gravitationally-lensed deep field image.  I say 'maybe' because we don't yet know if these will be the farthest galaxies ever viewed, but it's possible.

Here's the list of the targets in the first data dump:

- **Carina Nebula** The Carina Nebula is one of the largest and brightest nebulae in the sky, located approximately 7,600 light-years away in the southern constellation Carina. Nebulae are stellar nurseries where stars form. The Carina Nebula is home to many massive stars, several times larger than the Sun.
- **WASP-96 b (spectrum)** WASP-96 b is a giant planet outside our solar system, composed mainly of gas. The planet, located nearly 1,150 light-years from Earth, orbits its star every 3.4 days. It has about half the mass of Jupiter, and its discovery was announced in 2014.
- **Southern Ring Nebula** The Southern Ring, or “Eight-Burst” nebula, is a planetary nebula – an expanding cloud of gas, surrounding a dying star. It is nearly half a light-year in diameter and is located approximately 2,000 light years away from Earth.
- **Stephan’s Quintet** About 290 million light-years away, Stephan’s Quintet is located in the constellation Pegasus. It is notable for being the first compact galaxy group ever discovered in 1877. Four of the five galaxies within the quintet are locked in a cosmic dance of repeated close encounters.
- **SMACS 0723** Massive foreground galaxy clusters magnify and distort the light of objects behind them, permitting a deep field view into both the extremely distant and intrinsically faint galaxy populations.

The last item is the one to watch.

Reference:

[NASA Shares List of Cosmic Targets for Webb Telescope’s First Images](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2022/nasa-shares-list-of-cosmic-targets-for-webb-telescope-s-first-images)

Answer (score 1):

> Are first official science images of JWST are most far distant images ever taken by space telescope?

We won't know until they show us (be patient; it's less than a week away), but the answer is almost a certainty that that will not be the case. It took about about a decade for the Hubble Space Telescope to collect over time the imagery that ultimately became the [Hubble eXtreme Deep Field](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/hubble/science/xdf.html). The JWST has only been near-operational for a few weeks. (I wrote "near operational" because one mode, NIRCAM Coronography, has yet to be commissioned.) The JWST simply has not had enough time yet to gather those extremely deep space images. It will do so, eventually. Please be patient.

Answer (score 1):

NASA released a [test image](https://blogs.nasa.gov/webb/2022/07/06/webbs-fine-guidance-sensor-provides-a-preview/) a couple of days ago "using 72 exposures over 32 hours".  And the text says it's "among the deepest images of the universe ever taken".  So it is very likely the first science images will be too.

[image]